# Change HTML code in summernote while typing without focus loss

Tags: javascript, summernote

After keyUp event has triggered I want to validate the current text (something like spell verification). The Problem is, that every time I lose the focus of my editor and the last cursor's position.
I built a method, which returns the validated HTML code. The new HTML code contains the validated text with its errors wrapped with `<span class='error'></span>`. Theoretically I should only replace the old HTML code with the new one. But It's not that easy:

Simplified example:

`Text without validation (raw Text): This is an example for an eror`

`Validated text (HTML): This is an example for an <span class='error'>eror</span>`

The view:
[image]

Simplified Codes:

```
function validate(text){
    //some code
    return new_html;
}

function onKeyUpSummernote(){
    var text = jQuery(summernote("code")).text();
    var new_html = validate(text);
    summernote("saveRange");
    summernote("code", new_html);
    summernote("focus");
    summernote("restoreRange");
}
```

But this doesn't work, because I get the following error:
`The given range isn't in document.`

How can I change the html Code after KeyUp and set the cursor to the last position? Is there any better way to do this?